# Android studio, Ctrl+BackSpace delete same as eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

I migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio, but I loved eclipse ability to delete `camelCase` names by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd>. It deletes from current position of cursor to the first Capital word in Eclipse, but Android Studio deletes the whole word with the same shortcut. How can I do he same as eclipse in AS?

The second question is about scrolling- in Eclipse <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`Mouse Wheel` cases scrolling a page, is it possible to do the same in AS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open up your Android Studio keymap by going to File > Settings, then selecting "Keymap" on the left.

The first option (Eclipse's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>) is called "Delete to Word Start in Different 'CamelHumps' Mode." You can assign it to whatever keybinding works best for you.

As for the second option- it sounds like <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>PageDown</kbd> provide the functionality you are looking for. I'm not aware of a way to make the mouse's scroll wheel perform page scrolling.

Answer (score 3):

To delete one word at a time using `CTRL+backspace` turn this setting on:

> File -> Settings -> Editor -> Smart Keys -> "Use CamelHumps words"